# Is there any software (preferably Linux) that, when managing a database, can inform you about opening transpositions?

Tags: software, database

To make it simple, let's say that I play a game that opens with 1. e4 d5 2. d4.

I use Scid-vs-PC, and in this position, it just shows a bunch of games. Od course, if black plays now 2 ... e6, we transpose into the French defense, and suddenly thousands of games exist.

I'm looking for a software that after 1. e4 d5 2. d4 will show you the games that transpose to the French Defense.

I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself properly. So, just in case, this site has this feature that I'm attaching a picture of to show both cases in [chesstempo](https://chesstempo.com/game-database.html)

[image]
[image: chesstempo showing the option e6 after 1 e4 d5 2 d4]

Comment: Scid is pretty good at doing this. What more do you need than what it does?

Comment: If I open one of those large databases with scid and play something like 1. e4 d5 2. d4 it will show 2. ... e6 as a played move, but will only show some hundreds of games. Only after you play e6 on the board scid "realises" of the transposition and shows thousands of games available.
I want that scid (or any other program) realises beforehand that after 2... e6 there's a transposition with thousands of games.

Comment: Ah. But that leads to confusion -- say if you play 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.Nxe5??, it'll show that 3...Nf6 was played tens of thousands of times because of 1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nf6 3.Nxe5 d6. In the position 1.e4 d5 2.d4, 2...dxe4 is a better and more popular move than 2...e6. I think there is another question out there about this difference that might be useful, but I don't know which.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought about that kind of issues. In any case maybe it could be done in a way that you're warned that it's a transposition.
Or maybe it could check if some moves have been done that lead to transpositions (so avoiding funny situations like the one you posted).

Comment: It's mostly a speed issue though -- the way Scid does it in e.g. the Tree window, it has to go through the database to find all games with this specific position, and then show statistics for what happened in each. What you want would require searching the database again for each resulting position. But it would give better statistics on the resulting position, yes.

Comment: Maybe this is the post you commented above:
https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/scid-not-recognising-transpositions

Right there it's commented that this software has that feature (it's windows only though)

http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/download

Comment: In chessbase if the reference database shows more games after making a move than the number of games before the move, then this implies a transposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It may implicitly 'know' internally but none of them explicitly tell you there is/are/couldbe transpositions.